# cannot access rich components in java script using #{rich:component(Id)} or RichFaces.$(Id)

Tags: javascript, richfaces, jsf-1.2

Newbie at javascript here. Trying to access the internals of RichFaces components with examples I find on the web, without much luck.

RichFaces 3.3 and JSF 1.2, jboss server, Chrome, ant.

I've seen examples like

```
#{rich:component(formId)}
RichFaces.$(stHourId)
```

But neither is recognized when executed.
So how can I use these or access them otherwise ...

- Are these not available in RichFaces 3.3 ? If not, is there a way to do the example below in 3.3?
- Do I need something special in my xhtml file to be able to use these, or in web.xml or faces-config.xml or ?

#### HERE'S THE SPECIFIC EXAMPLE:

access the value list of a rich:comboBox in javascript - found an example on the web

```
var valueArray = #{rich:component(formId)}.comboList.itemsValue;
```

I get an error when the page loads :  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .**
When I look at the code in the developer tool console, the #{rich:component(formid)} is **completely missing** (which causes other problems)

```
var valueArray = .comboList.itemsValue;
```

If I remove that line but break in the code, and try to manually use #{rich:component...}  in the console,

```
#{rich:component('form:recurStartMincomboboxField')}
```

I get : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
or

```
RichFaces.$('form:recurStartMincomboboxField')
```

a different error: **Uncaught TypeError: RichFaces.$ is not a function**

I know the form Id is correct since the following works, but I can't seem to access the value list from this

```
document.getElementById('form:recurStartMincomboboxField')
```

and If you want to see it in context, relevant parts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"> 

<head>    
    <script>         
        function checkMinute(formId, defaultVal) {
            alert('validateMinute');

            var minuteStr = document.getElementById(formId).value;

            // get list of values allowed for the combobox
            var valueArray = #{rich:component(formId)}.comboList.itemsValue;      
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <h:form id="form">

    ......

        <rich:comboBox id="recurStartMin" value="#{filterManagerBean.recurStartMin}" required="false" 
                       selectFirstOnUpdate="true" defaultLabel="" enableManualInput="true" width="50"
                       onchange="checkMinute('form:recurStartMincomboboxField', '00')"
                       > 
             <f:selectItems value="#{filterManagerBean.minuteOptions}" />
        </rich:comboBox>

    ......

    </h:form>
</body> 

</html>
```

Been trying various things and searches all day, pretty frustrated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#{rich:component('recurStartMincomboboxField')}
```

This is Expression Language (EL) not JavaScript, see the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html).

You cannot execute EL on the client side since that's for the server to work with (it's kind of like inline Java code). EL expressions are executed as the page loads so if you want to use it you have to know the id beforehand, or the id has to be available on the server. Or you can use pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('form:recurStartMincomboboxField').component
```

`RichFaces.$` is not available in RichFaces 3.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using the #{rich:component..} in the wrong place!
I did try the document.getElementById(...).component, but it is undefined in the javascript.
However, I was able to use the rich:component expression in the parameter to the onchange function, sending the list of items to the function:   
onchange="checkMinute('form:recurStartMincomboboxField', '00', #{rich:component('form:recurStartMin')}.comboList.itemsText)"

Interesting note to self, the id must be the actual id name in the rich:component call versus using the expanded name 'form:recurStartMincomboboxField'.

Comment: And turns out you CAN do document.getElementById(...).component in the java script, but must use the actual id name, versus the "expanded" name (...comboboxField). Tricky... so this worked:

    document.getElementById('form:recurStartMin').component.comboList.itemsText; ............. Makhiel, if you correct that statement in your answer, I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rose I just copied that from your code (for the record it works with both versions of the id in RichFaces 4, I would've assumed it did in RF 3 as well). I any case on client side you have to use to the full id.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `facelets`,  add

```
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

[example combo boxes](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?c=comboBox&tab=usage)

This [extended example](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EnhancedRichcomboBoxValuesnotOnlyTextAndRegExpSuggestions) shows the use of `jQuery` and `val()` in working with this. As with anything very new do the tutorials using exactly the data and details in the examples first to iron out minor issues.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and especially thanks for pointing out that extended example - doing some interesting stuff in there I didn't know was possible